# How to instantly update the dataTableOutput while using local persistent storage

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I needed persistent storage to show all the records ever inputed and I achieved them as follows:

```
humanTime <- function() format(Sys.time(), "%d%m%Y-%H%M%OS")

formData <- reactive({
  data <- sapply(fieldsAll, function(x) input[[x]])
  #data <- c(data, timestamp = humanTime())
  data <- t(data)
  data
})

saveData <- function(data) {
  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                      humanTime(),
                      digest::digest(data))

  write.csv(x = data, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
            row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}

# action to take when submit button is pressed
observeEvent(input$submit, {
  saveData(formData())
})
```

And displayed the data as this:

```
output$responsesTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
  loadData(),
  rownames = FALSE,
  options = list(searching = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE,server=TRUE)
)
```

And it works fine showing me all the records ever inputed. But the problem is the datable doesn't reflect the data as soon as I click on submit. I refresh my app(pressing F5) and when I check now the recently input data is also updated in the data table.

Is there any way to make it display as soon as I click on Submit (actionButton).

I also need to change the headers of the DataTableOutput. For E.g if the inputId is "aname", the data table has the column header as "aname" but I need it as "Associate Name" as I given in the label.

```
textInput("aname", "Associate Name")
```

Comment: Two methods: (1) your reactive data should react to new data, combine/save the data to the file, then return this data from the `reactive` (ergo, using `formData()` still for all data), this will provide the *fastest* results; (2) if you might have other processes append to the file (csv is likely not your best format) or if you want to change to new file contents, then look at `shiny::reactiveFileReader`, which polls periodically for updates to the file and allows you to do something with that information (such as pull in its data).

Comment: P.S : I have tried dataTableProxy but couldn't succeed

Comment: I believe this is about managing *data*, not displaying it, so it's not a surprise to me that `DT::dataTableProxy` is not yet being fruitful.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for your suggestions. This is my first shiny app and I'm not sure how to proceed further. I don't think I can use ```shiny::reactiveFileReader``` since ```saveData <- function(data) {
  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                      humanTime(),
                      digest::digest(data))

  write.csv(x = data, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
            row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}``` creates a new file for each entry say 20 files for 20 entries.Please help me with the workaround.

Comment: Is this supporting concurrent users? Is it intended to survive an app restart?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to show all the data even if we close the App and open again.

Comment: Suggestions: since it can be concurrent users, the use of CSV might work much of the time but when it fails, you'll corrupt your data. I suggest you go with some database, perhaps SQLite (which has a very low buy-in effort), and use `invalidateLater` or `reactiveFileReader` on the sqlite file to update when something changes.